# What to do when you branch out from the wrong branch and have unwanted commits?

Tags: git, github

I've made a mistake and when I wanted to branch out for a feature I forgot to change to the dev branch and create a new branch from there... Instead I created a new branch while being inside another feature branch.

I just pushed my feature branch I have just finished and realized that there is commits from another feature branch (the one I created the branch from) while doing a pull request.

What do I do in this situation because I now have a branch with a load of commits from another feature branch on git hub? Can I remove them or what is the best solution for me? I am no git expert so I may need help with the commands I may need to run.

Thanks.

Comment: you could check out your feature branch and `rebase wherever_you_meant_to_branch_from`. delete the remote, re `push`.

Comment: How would I do that and would that still keep the commits I made in my feature branch?

Comment: Rebase switches out the branch that your feature branch is based on. It will rewind your commits, switch out the underlying branch, and then replay your commits. If you're nervous, make a copy of the entire project folder just in case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use rebase command to edit your commit tree. For example, considering you have the following commits:

```
* h121j commit A
* kj13i commit B
* alk29 unwanted commit
* a4b2i commit C
```

You can do: `git rebase -i a4b2i`. It will open an editor and you will be able to simply remove the commit (or mark to edition, if you want).

```
pick alk29 unwanted commit
pick kj13i commit B
pick h121j commit A

# Rebase a4b2i..h121j onto a0220ae (3 commands)
#
# Commands:
...
```

All you need to do is remove the line `pick alk29 unwanted commit`. When you save it, the commits lines removed will be removed from the commit tree.

Comment: Are the 5-character alphanumeric identifiers supposed to be the Git abbreviated commit ID? Shouldn’t they be hexadecimal?

Comment: Yep @DanielH, but they are not valid, I just tap the keys of my keyboard :)

Comment: Is there anyway I can do this without knowing the commit ID, as I have about 10 commits to remove and it would be easier to just open this editor from the start?

Comment: --interactive will set the IDs on the screen for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.... two parts:

1 Cherry-pick the unwanted commits to the place where you really want them to be

2 Just reset --hard the local branch to the place where it should be (without the unwanted commits) and then push --force it into the remote. As a matter of fact, there's no need to reset --hard locally. You can push-force by providing the right ID you want on the remote branch: `git push --force the-remote right-revision-id:remote-branch`

Comment: So my feature branch is called feature/validate-messages and I created it from feature/Auth-System, so there is commits from the Auth-System branch inside feature/validate-messages and I was suppose to create the validate-messages branch from my dev branch. So if I am correct I should run this: `git push --force origin dev:feature/validate-messages` ? What will that do and will it keep the commits I made in feature/validate-messages and just remove the commits from the Auth-System branch?

Comment: Not really. Let's assume there are **3** commits that are part of feature/validate-messages that you put on top of feature/Auth-System (and that feature/Auth-System is correctly pointed on the right revision both locally and remotely). If that's the case: ```git checkout --detach dev; git cherry-pick feature/validate-messages~3..feature/validate-messages; git branch -f feature/validate-messages; git push -f origin feature/validate-messages```. Give or take.

Comment: Ok, I think the first option seems easier, but I have about 10 commits to remove, but how would I chery pick 10 commits out?

Comment: replace ~3 for ~10